# How can I split large files?

Tags: linux

I have a large CSV file (7.3GB; 16,300,000 lines), how can I split this file into two files?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Have you taken a look at the `split` command?  See [this](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?split) **man** page for more information.

This [page](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/split-a-text-file-in-half-or-any-percentage-on-ubuntu-linux/) contains an example use of this command.

Aside:

the `man -k` command is rather useful for finding unix/linux commands if you aren't quite sure what the specific command is. Specify a keyword with the man -k command and the system will pull out related commands. E.g.,

```
% man -k split
```

will yield:

```
csplit (1)           - split a file into sections determined by context lines
dirsplit (1)         - splits directory into multiple with equal size
dpkg-split (1)       - Debian package archive split/join tool
gpgsplit (1)         - Split an OpenPGP message into packets
pnmsplit (1)         - split a multi-image portable anymap into multiple single-image files
ppmtoyuvsplit (1)    - convert a portable pixmap into 3 subsampled raw YUV files
split (1)            - split a file into pieces
splitdiff (1)        - separate out incremental patches
splitfont (1)        - extract characters from an ISO-type font.
URI::Split (3pm)     - Parse and compose URI strings
wcstok (3)           - split wide-character string into tokens
yuvsplittoppm (1)    - convert a Y- and a U- and a V-file into a portable pixmap
zipsplit (1)         - split a zipfile into smaller zipfiles
```

Comment: @spk: The syntax is correct, but this would split your file into 3,260,000 files. You should choose a higher value, any amount higher than 8,150,000 and lesser than 16,300,000 will create two files.

Comment: Like @spk mentioned selecting the right values will do what you want. If any of the questions you've asked on SO provided the right answer to your questions, feel free to accept them - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: When using `split` to split CSV files, note that the CSV header is not repeated for each file.

Answer (score 1):

split -d -n l/N filename.csv tempfile.part.

splits the file into N files without splitting lines. As mentioned in the comments above, the header is not repeated in each file.