# splitting files in unix

Tags: performance, unix, split, bigdata

Just wondering if there is a faster way to split a file into N chunks other than unix "split".

Basically I have large files which I would like to split into smaller chunks and operate on each one in parallel.

Comment: not sure what calls for a -1 on this question but that's ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using `split -b` which will be more CPU-efficient than splitting by lines, but still reads the whole input file and writes it out to each file.   If the serial nature of the execution of this portion of `split` is your bottleneck, you can use `dd` to extract the chunks of the file in parallel.   You will need a distinct `dd` command for each parallel process.   Here's one example command line (assuming `the_input_file` is a large file this extracts a bit from the middle):

```
dd skip=400 count=1 if=the_input_file bs=512 of=_output
```

To make this work you will need to choose appropriate values of `count` and `bs` (those above are very small).   Each worker will also need to choose a different value of `skip` so that the chunks don't overlap.  But this is efficient; `dd` implements `skip` with a seek operation.

Of course, this is still not as efficient as implementing your data consumer process in such a way that it can read a specified chunk of the input file directly, in parallel with other similar consumer processes.   But I assume if you could do that you would not have asked this question.

Answer (score 0):

Given that this is an OS utility, my inclination would be to think that it's optimized for best performance.

You can see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10571376/how-can-i-split-large-files/10571386#10571386) (or do a `man -k split` or `man split`) to find related commands that you might be able to use instead of `split`.

If you are thinking of implementing your own solution in say C, then I would suggest you run some benchmarks this for your own specific system/environment and some sample data and determine what tool to use.

*Note*: if you aren't going to be doing this regularly, it may not be worth your while to even think about this much, just go ahead and use a tool that does what you need it to do (in this case `split`)